# Vaadin 14 with spring security - Push mode stopping http session from invalidating

Tags: spring-boot, vaadin-flow, vaadin14

We are using `maxInactiveInterval` in our vaadin 14 application to invalidate an http session after a certain amount of time to logout inactive users. It is currently set to 30 min.

```
UI.getCurrent().getSession().getSession().setMaxInactiveInterval(1800);
```

We set the heartbeat interval slightly above that timer so that the heartbeats don't interfere with the inactive timer. After the user was beeing inactive in the UI for those 30 min, the http session will be invalidated (through spring I guess) and any further UI interaction after that will automatically redirect the user to our login page.

This strategy has been working for a while until we implement Vaadin push mode to our MainFrame to do some non blocking background loading on a different thread. With push mode active, a websocket will be opened and every 5 min the application will send messages through `vaadinPush-min.js` which keeps the http session alive so that it cannot be invalidated. It is currently set to PushMode automatic, but we've tried it with PushMode manual as well. Every 5 min those four messages will be sent from the frontend through  `vaadinPush-min.js`:

```
ajaxRequest.onreadystatechange, new state: 4
invoking .close() on WebSocket object
Firing onReconnect
ajaxrequest.onerror
```

I guess it has something to do with vaadin push mode opening a websocket connection to have constant data flow and the socket needs to be somehow kept alive, but those messages keep currently preventing an automated user logout.

Is there a way to stop the vaadin push websocket from constantly sending these messages? Or is there a way to increase the timer those messages will be send? If not, is there a way to only open the websocket from Vaadin push mode for only a short period of time instead of beeing constantly open?

#### Note

If I decrease `maxInactiveInterval` to a value less than 5 min the http session will be invalidated correctly, it's just not an option for us to decrease it down to such a value.

#### specs

- vaadin 14.8.1
- spring-boot-starter-parent 2.5.8
- java 1.8